# How to compare the length of words in an input text and sort them according to length value

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap

I have a string of words which I want to return sorted according to their length. Some words are repeated more than once, so I am using HashMap to return the words and their count:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

for (String s : fragments) {
    if (map.containsKey(s)) {
        map.put(s, map.get(s) + 1);
    } else {
        map.put(s, 1);
    }

}
```

How can I use this to return the length of each word and  sort them from longest to shortest?

Edit:
For example, if the input is a string

```
"From the torrent, or the fountain,From the red cliff of the mountain"
```

and I do a simple loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < fragments.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(fragments[i]+" " +fragments[i].length());
}
```

the output is: (full output re:@Pshemo)

```
from 4
the 3
or 2
the 3
the 3
red 3
cliff 5
of 2
the 3
mountain 8
```

and so on. It's unsorted and the words like "the" repeat each time it sees the word. I want to not repeat the duplicates and sort the words from longest to shortest.

The output I want should be:

```
mountain 8
cliff 5
from 4
the 3
red 3
of 2
or 2
```

Comment: Integrate a bubble sort: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort

Comment: You told us that `some words are repeated more than once` but you didn't tell about consequences of this fact. Do you want to let duplicate values or not?

Comment: @Pshemo I am implementing HashMap so that we don't see same word printed out more than once - the only way we know it appears more than once is by seeing the word's count. Same with the length, I don't want to output same word twice.

Comment: From what I see you don't even need such map of words and number of their occurrences to solve your problem. Maybe post example with input and expected output to bet better help.

Comment: @Pshemo I edited my question, now it has examples. I am also not sure that I need HashMap at all. I'm very new to Java so I'm pretty much at a loss here.

Comment: You are saying `I want to not repeat the duplicates` but your example contains `the 3` twice and there is no `torrent` and many other words. Honestly I am confused even more then at start.

Comment: Maybe pick some simpler (shorted) example, analyse it fully and show correct (also full) expected output, preferably with explanation why  is it correct.

Comment: @Pshemo In my question, after the output example i say `"It's unsorted and the words like "the" repeat each time it sees the word. I want to not repeat the duplicates and sort the words from longest to shortest."`

Updated the post again for further clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a custom Comparator:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String phrase = "From the torrent, or the fountain, From the red cliff of the mountain";
    //or whatever method of getting the individual words you want.
    //I just chose StringTokenizer (obviously)
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(phrase, " ,");
    TreeSet<String> ts = new TreeSet<>(new Comparator<String>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
            int retVal = Integer.compare(s1.length(), s2.length());
            if(retVal == 0){
                retVal = s1.compareTo(s2);
            }
            return retVal;
        }
    });
    while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
        ts.add(st.nextToken());
    }
    for(String s : ts.descendingSet()){
        System.out.println(s + " " + s.length());
    }
}
```

It'll even alphabetize words of the same length :-)

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain what does StringTokenizer do?

Comment: Oopsy. I had that final for loop iterating in increasing size. Fixed to be descending how you asked.

Comment: StringTokenizer - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html

Comment: So if I already break down the string into an array of words, then I shouldn't use the tokenizer.

Comment: Yeah, you wouldnt need it. This is just a completely stand alone example. If you've already got the array, then just iterate through it and add the words to the TreeSet. With that custom comparator in place, it'll sort them for you as you add them (as demonstrated). So instead of the while loop, just do a for(String s : yourArray){ts.add(s);} And since it's a Set, it automatically throws out duplicates.

Comment: +1 but as mentioned in StringTokenizer documentation *"`StringTokenizer` is a **legacy** class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the `split` method of String or the `java.util.regex` package instead"*. Your `while(st.hasMoreTokens()){ ts.add(st.nextToken());` can be simply replaced with `for (String token : phrase.split("[\\s,]+")) ts.add(token);`

Comment: Yeah. What he said. Guess I'm just old skool...me and my StringTokenizers will report to a retirement home now.